# AWS SDK sample error

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-ec2

I currently downloaded and installed the AWS sdk on an EC2 instance using mvn package and everything seemed to install correctly. When I try to run the DynamoDB sameple, it fails with all this:

```
AmazonDynamoDBSample.java:18: error: package com.amazonaws does not exist
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
                    ^
AmazonDynamoDBSample.java:19: error: package com.amazonaws does not exist
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
                    ^
AmazonDynamoDBSample.java:20: error: package com.amazonaws.auth does not exist
import com.amazonaws.auth.ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider;
                     ^
```

It seems as though the AWS sdk didn't install properly. Any help?

Comment: This looks like a class path issue. Can you please verify that the aws-java-sdk jar is present? also, how do you run the samples?

Answer (score 3):

create a maven project and add the following dependency in your pom.xml everything would work fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```